# Bottom bracket upgrade

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket, upgrades

I want to upgrade the components on my bike.  I want to start with the crankset.  I'm just sourcing parts/tools at the moment. It originally came with 113mm spindle sealed cartridge. The bottom bracket shell is 68mm English.  Can I upgrade to Shimano, Campagnolo, or Sram components?  I know it would most likely be cheaper buying a new bike but I can't do that at this time.  Thanks.

Comment: *I want to upgrade the components on my bike.*  Unless you're really, really good at finding bargains, [economies of scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economies_of_scale) and other factors make it a lot cheaper to just buy a new bike at the level you want than it is to buy parts piece-by-piece to get there.  And for what it's worth, upgrading a working crankset is probably not going to change your bike's performance all that much anyway.

Comment: Road bike or MTB? What components do you have now?

Comment: I have an 05 Giant OCR2.

Comment: I agree with Argenti Apparatus answer of reviewing the drivetrain on a whole, rather than the crank alone.  I had a look at the spec of the 2005 Giant OCR 2 and it originally came with a TruVativ Touro, 30/42/52 teeth and a 9 speed groupset.  If you would replace the crankset, make sure it's a triple or your shifter and front derailleur won't work.  The triple provides a wide gearing range as it is, so I wonder why you want to replace it.  Is it worn out?

Comment: If cost is leading in your decision making (and want to make sure 3x9 road compatibility, so no hacking/bodging), I expect Shimano Sora FC-3503 is the cheapest new part from Shimano.  On eBay I see new models for around USD38 (excl BB).  The recommended BB would be BB-RS500 on eBay new from USD18.

Comment: Also if the chain and cassette are old, I would recommend changing those as well as a worn out chain might hurt your new chainrings.  Normally the order of replacement is (most frequent listed first): 1. chain, 2. cassette, 3. chainrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget Campagnolo if you are on a budget. SRAM and Shimano both still make cranks/bottom brackets that are compatible with threaded bottom bracket shells, as do other component manufacturers like FSA.

Presumably you have a square taper bottom bracket axle. You can get a cranks that fit that, but you can run into [chainline](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chainline.html) problems because different cranks require a different axle length. Replacing both the crank and bracket at the same time often makes more sense.

I'd recommend looking at the whole drivetrain an asking yourself if you want to upgrade it as a whole, to get more gear ratios perhaps. That may require replacing many components at once. Just swapping a single component such as the crank may not bring any benefit.

Comment: If Campagnolo is too expensive, it's probably your local distributors' fault. At least in Europe mail order prices are competitive with similar quality from the other brands.

Comment: @ojs, yes, but Campi only makes medium to high end road groups. If the OP is *upgrading to* Shimano or SRAM they presumably have something like a Suntour or Sugino.

Comment: I'm not sure if entry level Shimano/SRAM is much improvement over entry level third party crank. The reason manufacturers install them at all is to save costs without sacrificing too much quality.

Comment: Today's Claris and Sora cranks are on par with 6400 and earlier Ultegra and better looking if not quite as light.

Comment: Entry level SRAM is certainly no upgrade